# Angularjs-ui bootstrap.tabs - Adding Next tab button

Tags: angularjs

I am using a modal to display a series of tabs using

```
<div class="modal fade hide modal-creator" data-backdrop="static" modal="imageUploader" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Create New Gallery</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="imageUploader_sort">
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" heading="{{tab.title}}" disabled="tab.disabled" select="tabName(tab.title)">
            <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
        </tab>
    </tabs>

</div><!-- /modal-body -->

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-click="close()" class="btn" >Close</button>
    <button ng-click="next()" class="btn" >Next</button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.tabs = [
        { title:"Home", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/create.html", active: true },
        { title:"Upload", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/upload.html"},
        { title:"Edit", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/edit.html"}
    ];
$scope.next = function()
    {
        console.log($scope.tabs);
    };
```

I am looking to create a solution to navigate through the tabs with a next button and when I reach the last page, turn the button into a finished button. Any guidance on this a  great help
 Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? When the next button is clicked take the index of the current tab and set that tabs active property to false. Then increment the index and set that tabs active property to true, Continue this until you reach the length of the tabs array. Once you do change the label of the button to finished.

Comment: thanks. where I'm running into an issue is getting the index for the current tab. and passing with ng-click="next();"

Comment: Well you will probably start off at index 0 correct? So create a scope variable in your controller that defaults to 0. `scope.tabIndex = 0;`. Then you can access and increment this value from your `$scope.next()` function with no need to pass it in.

Comment: understood, but not having a set value skipping tabs then becomes an issue?

Comment: If you want to skip a tab you would just add 2 to `$scope.tabIndex` or click the next button twice. Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h2J9nBSYtEI7hwCz2Xp8?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for your time on this. From your example, what if I navigate to tab 3 by clicking the tab, then I hit the next button. It takes me to tab 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35097/discussion-between-jonathan-palumbo-and-bungdaddy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should get you started down the right path.

http://plnkr.co/edit/h2J9nBSYtEI7hwCz2Xp8?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabIndex = 0;
  $scope.buttonLabel = "Next";

  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Step 1", content:" content 1", active: true },
    { title:"Step 2", content:" content 2" },
    { title:"Step 3", content:" content 3" },
    { title:"Step 4", content:" content 4" }
  ];

  $scope.proceed = function() {
     if($scope.tabIndex !== $scope.tabs.length -1 ){
      $scope.tabs[$scope.tabIndex].active = false;
      $scope.tabIndex++
      $scope.tabs[$scope.tabIndex].active = true;
     }

     if($scope.tabIndex === $scope.tabs.length -1){
        $scope.buttonLabel = "Finish";
     }
  };

  $scope.setIndex = function($index){
      $scope.tabIndex = $index;
  };

};
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here's a more complete answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/quIciaDlww1ngSrVgVeX?p=preview) that handles both direct navigation as well as clicking Next for the button state.

Besides tracking the selected tab using the `select` attribute, I also changed the way the button is displayed, by splitting it into two buttons.  This way the text is maintained within the view, and is independent of the model state.

```html
<button ng-show="!isLastTab()" class="btn btn-small" ng-click="proceed()">Next</button>
<button ng-show="isLastTab()" class="btn btn-small" ng-click="proceed()">Finish</button>
```

The JS looks like this now:

```js
$scope.selectedTab = 0;

$scope.tabSelected = function(index) {
    $scope.selectedTab = index;
}

var isLastTab = function() {
    return $scope.selectedTab === $scope.tabs.length-1;
}

$scope.isLastTab = isLastTab;

$scope.proceed = function() {
    if(!isLastTab()){
        $scope.selectedTab++;
        $scope.tabs[$scope.selectedTab].active = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: FYI: if you use the newer, unstable release of Angular instead, you can simplify the button by going back to one, without `ng-show`, and changing the label to `{{ isLastTab() ? 'Finish' : 'Next' }}`.