# Button inside one static tab to show second tab is not working when using angular ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want that on clicking a button inside one static tab would take me to another tab. I am trying using angular ui bootstrap but it is not working. I am using below code but it is not working-

```
 <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[2].active = true">Select third tab</button>

   </uib-tab>
```

I have created a plunker here- 
https://plnkr.co/edit/dTdsbeWbWiIqvmjh2IY8?p=preview

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Click to load sequence tab, check this verified answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132502/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-tabs-adding-next-tab-button?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="secondTab()">Select second tab</button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.secondTab = function(){
  $scope.active = 2;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/wZ8yIkjvoLO82wvG5UBc?p=preview